# Using a loop's positional parameters inside an inner loop in Raku

Tags: loops, raku, positional-parameter

Here is the code:

```
my @s=<a b c d>;
for @s.kv {
    for ($^k ... @s.elems) {
        printf("%s ", $^v);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Expected output is:

```
# a b c d
# b c d
# c d
# d
```

But it gives this error (possibly among others)

```
key 0, val 1 Too few positionals passed; expected 2 arguments but got 1
```

It looks like the positional variables of the main loop `$^k` and `$^v` can't be used inside the inner loop. How to fix it? Thanks.
Update: Typo inside inner loop fixed

Comment: The expected output 100% doesn't match your print statement. Also `($^k...@s.elems)` gives you indexes not the values.

Comment: Ops. It was a leftover from my notes. Updated that section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So for what you want to do I'd approach it like this :

```
my @s = <a b c d>;
for ^@s.elems -> $start-index {
    for @s[$start-index..*] -> $value {
        printf("%s ", $value );
    }
    print("\n");
}
```

Though really I'd do this.

```
my @s = <a b c d>;
(^@s.elems).map( { @s[$_..*].join(" ").say } )
```

Get the range from 0 to the number of elements in the array. Then the slice from there to the end for each, join on spaces and say.

A note on variables like `$^k` these are scoped to the current block only (hence why your above code is not working). Generally you only really want to use them in `map`, `grep` or other such things. Where possible I'd always advise naming your variables, this makes them scoped inside inner blocks as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How does the `^` in front of `^@s.elems` operate?

Comment: It's a short cut for the Range of 0..^@s.elems . (You don't want @s.elems itself because that's out of bounds).

Comment: `@s[$_..*].join(" ").say for ^@s` <-- A bit of golfing, hopefully considered elegant. LarsMalmsteen, `^` as a prefix coerces its operand to be a number, so `^@s` is a shortcut for `^@s.elems` (which is a shortcut for `0..^@s.elems`). I read `^foo` in my head as "up to `foo`", with a more precise expansion being "from zero up to *but not including* `foo`". So if there are 4 elements in `@s` then `^@s` is the same as `^4`, which iterates to `0, 1, 2, 3`.

Comment: The last paragraph added by @ScimonProctor as to why the `$^k` variable didn't work is quite helpful. And both one-liner solutions (by @ScimonProctor and @raiph) help learn the real language. And as for the usage of the `^` operator, I actually knew that but somehow it got out of my mind. I will go through its explanations, they're valuable to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Scimon Proctor's answer is essentially correct, but I'll try to explain why your example does not work. For starters, [`kv`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/kv) returns "an interleaved sequence of indexes and values", so this:

```
my @s=<a b c d>;
.say for @s.kv;
```

prints

```
0
a
1
b
2
c
3
d
```

Essentially, you're doing one turn of the loop for every key *and* value. Grouping them in pairs using [`rotor`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/rotor) might be closer to what you're looking for:

```
.say for @s.kv.rotor(2)
```

which will return:

```
(0 a)
(1 b)
(2 c)
(3 d)
```

Since with this we got the value couple with the index, we can do...

```
my @s=<a b c d>;
for @s.kv.rotor(2) -> ($k, $) {
    "{@s[$_]} ".print for ($k..^@s.elems);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Please note that there was also an error in the inner loop, whose range went beyond the actual indices in @s. But, again, Scimon's answer that uses maps is much shorter, idiomatic and straightforward. This one is just kind of dwimming your original program. As a matter of fact, we are throwing away the values, so this would actually be:

```
my @s=<a b c d>;
for @s.keys -> $k {
    "{@s[$_]} ".print for ($k..^@s.elems);
    printf("\n");
}
```

No need to use kv at all, and just make do with the [keys](https://docs.raku.org/routine/keys).

Comment: @raiph there's actually a better way to do it, I just edited it. But you're right, as always, and thanks.

Comment: @jmerelo :) :) :) <-- extra smilies cuz SO insists a comment must be longer than one, and it made me smile to see a further improvement, and cuz you're you.

Comment: Good to see an explanation on why the `.kv` construct didn't work. Using `.kv` with the `rotor is a good idea, too.

Comment: Alternatively, for the `rotor` example, one could let the block's signature grabs however many arguments are needed for each turn of the loop (e.g., `for @s.kv -> $k, $ { ... }`). As always, TIMTOADY though ;-)!